# Parsing JSON using GSON to get "content"

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been trying to get a list of all reservations from JSON using  GSON but keep getting an error. Am I doing something wrong? If yes then how should I fix this?

My try:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Wrapper reservations = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Wrapper.class);
```

Class:

```
class Wrapper{
    Long id;
    Long personId;
    List<Long> SeatsIDs;
}
```

PS Is there a solution in GSON to get rid of all the "links"?

```
 {
  "links": [
    {
      // a lot of stuff
    }
  ],
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "personID": 12335,
      "seatsIDs": [
        5,
        7,
        4
      ],
      "links": [
        {
           // a lot of stuff
        },
        {
           // a lot of stuff
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "personID": 77777,
      "seatsIDs": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "links": [
        {
           // a lot of stuff
        },
        {
           // a lot of stuff
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what error you have ?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a description of your error. But from what I see you would like to deserialize the each entry from the *content* array. However you ask GSON to deserialize the full response.

One possible solution will be to create a class structure that looks like your Json:

```
// Getters and setters omitted
class Response {
  List<Link> links;
  List<Wrapper> content; 
}
// ...
Response response = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Response.class);
Wrapper first = response.getContent().get(0);
```